# How to count a number of unique documents by a nested field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query, cardinality

I'm trying to count documents with unique nested field value (and next, the documents itself also). Looks like getting the unique documents works.
But when I'm trying to execute a request for `count`, I'm getting an error as follows:

> Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/package/_count?ignore_throttled=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"request does not support [collapse]","line":1,"col":216}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"request does not support [collapse]","line":1,"col":216},"status":400}

The code:

```
        BoolQueryBuilder innerTemplNestedBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        NestedQueryBuilder templatesNestedQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("attachment", innerTemplNestedBuilder, ScoreMode.None);
        BoolQueryBuilder mainQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(templatesNestedQuery);
        if (!isEmpty(templateName)) {
            innerTemplNestedBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("attachment.name", templateName));
        }
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource()
                    .collapse(new CollapseBuilder("attachment.uuid"))
                    .query(mainQueryBuilder);
    // NEXT LINE CAUSE ERROR
        long count = client.count(new CountRequest("package").source(searchSourceBuilder), RequestOptions.DEFAULT).getCount(); <<<<<<<<<< ERROR HERE
        // THIS WORKS 
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(
                    new SearchRequest(
                            new String[] {"package"},
                            searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).from(offset).size(limit)
                    ).indices("package").searchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH),
                    RequestOptions.DEFAULT
        );
        return ....;
```

The overall intention of approach is to get a portion of documents and the number of all such documents. May be there is another approach for this need already exists. If I'm trying to get `count` using `aggregations` and `cardinality` - I'm getting the zero result and it looks like it doesn't work on the nested fields.

Count request:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "attachment",
                        "ignore_unmapped": false,
                        "score_mode": "none",
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "collapse": {
        "field": "attachment.uuid"
    }
}
```

How mapping created:

```
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/package?pretty"
curl -X PUT    "localhost:9200/package?include_type_name=true&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "settings" :  {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    }}'
curl -X PUT    "localhost:9200/package/_mappings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties" : {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "uuid" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                "name" : { "type" : "text" }
            }
        },
        "uuid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
}
'
```

result query generated by code should be something like this:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/package/_count?&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "query" :
    {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "attachment",
                        "ignore_unmapped": false,
                        "score_mode": "none",
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "collapse": {
        "field": "attachment.uuid"
    }
}'
```

Comment: Can you dump the query that your java(?) query builder actually produces? A sample of your documents plus your mapping would be useful too. You won't be able to pase them in the comments so just edit your question please.

Comment: @jzzfs edited - added count request and index mapping

Comment: @jzzfs updated also error message for more precise

Comment: If i'm trying to get total number using '_search' - still getting un-collapsed value as 'total'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapsing can [only be used](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-collapse.html#search-request-collapse) in the `_search` context, not in `_count`.

Secondly, what does your query even do? You've got a lot of redundant parameters there like `boost:1` etc. You might as well say:

```
POST /package/_count?&pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attachment",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which does not really do anything :)

---

### **To answer your original question** of "counting documents with unique nested field value",

let's imagine 3 documents, 2 of which have the same `attachment.uuid` value:

```
[
  {
    "attachment":{
      "uuid":"04144e14-62c3-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003"
    }
  },
  {
    "attachment":{
      "uuid":"04144e14-62c3-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003"
    }
  },
  {
    "attachment":{
      "uuid":"100b9632-62c3-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003"
    }
  }
]
```

To get the `terms` breakdown of the `uuid`s, run

```
GET package/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_uniques": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attachment"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "subagg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attachment.uuid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which yields

```
...
{
  "aggregations":{
    "nested_uniques":{
      "doc_count":3,
      "subagg":{
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
        "sum_other_doc_count":0,
        "buckets":[
          {
            "key":"04144e14-62c3-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003",
            "doc_count":2
          },
          {
            "key":"100b9632-62c3-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003",
            "doc_count":1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### To get the the parent doc count of unique nested fields, we're gonna have to get slightly more clever:

```
GET package/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_uniques": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attachment"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "scripted_uniques": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "state.my_map = [:];",
            "map_script": """
              if (doc.containsKey('attachment.uuid')) {
                state.my_map[doc['attachment.uuid'].value.toString()] = 1;
              }
            """,
            "combine_script": """
              def sum = 0;
              for (c in state.my_map.entrySet()) {
                sum += 1
              }
              return sum
            """,
            "reduce_script": """
              def sum = 0;
              for (agg in states) {
                sum += agg;
              }
              return sum;
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which returns

```
...
{
  "aggregations":{
    "nested_uniques":{
      "doc_count":3,
      "scripted_uniques":{
        "value":2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this `scripted_uniques: 2` is exactly what you're after.

---

*Note: I solved this use case using nested scripted metric aggs but if any of you know of a cleaner approach, I'm more than happy to learn it!*

Comment: thanks it works. Not sure how it will work under load on lots of documents, but it's the only working approach so far...

Comment: No prob. I have it working with ~500k heavily nested docs. It takes a few seconds but never fails/times out.